# Laurent Series for $f(z)=\frac{9z-1}{(z^2-9)(z^3+1)}$ in annulus $1<|z|<3$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

> I want to find the Laurent series inside $1<|z|<3$ for $$f(z)=\dfrac{9z-1}{(z^2-9)(z^3+1)}$$

I asked a similar question earlier but now I have to combine it together and I'm not too sure how.

So for my partial fractions I got $\dfrac{-1}{6(z+3)}$ , $\dfrac{1}{6(z-3)}$ , $\dfrac{1}{(z^3+1)}$
So what I've done is to take partial fractions and ended up with the answer

$$f(z)=(-1/18)\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n(z/3)^n-(1/18)\sum_{n=0}^\infty (z/3)^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n z^(n-2)$$

I'm not sure if this is right though

Comment: Not right. The second series diverges for $|z|>1$.

Comment: @Artem It should be z/3 my mistake. Let me edit it

Comment: It still looks incorrect. You need to type first your partial fractions.

Comment: @Artem You mean say what they where?

Comment: I mean that the expression for $f$ you have has 4 poles (zeros of denominator), and therefore must be a sum of 4 series. Moreover, three of these series must have negative powers of $z$ to converge. I do not see this in your expression.

Comment: @Artem well there's 5 poles. 3, -3 and then the 3 roots of unity

Comment: I would suggest first then to check what you typed, add all the work you did, and only after this ask your question. Clearly, $z-9$ correspond to one series, if you meant $z^2-9$, then you made a typo twice.

Comment: @Artem Yeah I made a mistake again. I'm really bad at editing, but thanks for pointing it out. I would put all my working but I can't edit it.

Comment: The expansions of  $$f(z)=\frac{9z\color{red}{+}1}{(z^2-9)(z^3+1)}$$ and of $$f(z)=\frac{9z-1}{(z^2\color{red}{+}9)(z^3+1)}$$  would be particularly simple...

Comment: @Did I don't understand you?

Comment: ?? What I wrote: The expansions of two functions whose formulas are close to the one you asked about, would be simple to compute. What this remark suggests (but which is not necessary to understand my previous comment): You might have made a mistake in copying your assignment.

Comment: @Did The question is supposed to be tricky. It's lifted off an exam. Is my method right. Like splitting it into partial fractions then the series of each poiint

Comment: "Is my method right" The general idea of the method is correct but, since you do not show the details of what you did, it is difficult to say more.

Comment: @Did I have the original function at the top. I then take the partial fractions of said function which are given. And I know that 1/(1-z) gives a summation of z^n so I've manipulated each one to give me something similar to 1/(1-z)